# Real life projects for ASP.NET MVC and WCF

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4 and WCF. I know the basics and intend to give MS certification 70-486 (Developing ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Applications). I have good experience in ASP.NET, HTML, CSS, javascript and SharePoint development. 
Since the best way to learn is to actually implement some projects, I was wondering if there are any ASP.NET MVC projects that a beginner can start working on. I am not talking of completed sample projects, but given the requirements, a person has to build small projects.

I want to work on similar projects for WCF too.

Any help/links/resources would be very helpful.

Comment: You can check the "Pro ASP.NET MVC 5" book it starts with a simple example project and continues with more advanced practices in the next chapters.

Comment: This is good question but not for StackOverflow.

Comment: @KonradKokosa I do agree partially. This is more of a discussion. What is the other forums where I can post these kind of questions ?

Comment: Since you're looking for practice and experience, you may find it beneficial to look for questions here on these topics and try to answer them. It can be quite educational.

Comment: @TomZych good advice. I will work towards that.

Answer (score 2):

You can Check the **[Music Store App](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)** to get started with.

Other Useful Links :

1. [From Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683417/MVC-Beginners-Application)
2. [Beginners Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691517/Beginners-Guide-for-Designing-ASP-NET-MVC-Applicat)
3. [MVC 4 Beginners](http://mvc4beginner.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Go through from this link from day 1.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375182/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Step-by-Step-in

And for WCF you can go from

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/708138/CRUD-Operations-using-WCF-RESTful-Service-Part1

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/708138/CRUD-Operations-using-WCF-RESTful-Service-Part2